# Decompiling an RPM?

Tags: rpm

This is hopefully a simple question. Are there any tools out there to find out an enhanced description (beyond the normal rpm command) of the contents of an rpm, and possibly decompile it? We currently have an rpm from our company's security team which is supposed to be used for centralized authentication on our linux servers. The issue is that they can't supply source, and don't have a documented list of all changes that are made on the server. They did say that decompiling the rpm was ok.

So, any ideas??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [RPM2CPIO](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm2cpio) and [objdump](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice post that goes through various options of getting into packages: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/view-and-extract-packages/

Here's the gist of it for an RPM:

```
$ rpm2cpio package.rpm | cpio  -idmv
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `7zip` could extract the `rpm` to a `cpio` package, which again `7zip` could extract to expose the files that are placed in the system.